# Cordova CLI 5.0.0 - JavaScript error BlankCordovaApp

Tags: visual-studio-cordova

I am using the `JavaScript Blank Apache Cordova App`. Changes were made to the `config.xml` only.

I changed the Cordova CLI in `config.xml` from `4.3.0` to `5.0.0`. NPM downloaded the files, and no errors were reported.

When I F5 Debug > Android > Ripple. I get the following:
`"Exception occurred". Uncaught Error: cordova already defined`
[image]

This error does not appear when running `4.3.0`.  Any thoughts on why is would happen in `5.0.0`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this is a known issue with Ripple and the Android implementation in Cordova 5.0.0. The next point release will resolve it as the fix has been merged.

See the following dev mailing list thread on Cordova for details if you are interested: http://callback.markmail.org/message/so6xavs6xdfn45zv?q=+list:org%2Eapache%2Eincubator%2Ecallback-dev+Ripple

UPDATE: Cordova 5.1.1 is out and resolves this problem along with an Android security issue.

Comment: Chuck, Thanks again. I had looked at the Apache Cordova Know Issues page https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/cordova-known-issues-vs.aspx, but had no success.  The Microsoft Ignite presentation made the move from 4.3.0 to 5.0.0 look so simple :)

Comment: Yeah this is a newer issue - the update to the known issues is page is in progress which is why I could answer. :)

Comment: Chuck, I was able to debug using your dev mailing JavaScript fix to `cordova-js@3.9.1`. Made the recommended change in the cordova.js and AppData node_modules.
In addition, the visualstudio.com/en-us/features/cordova-known-issues-vs.aspx helped with the `gradle` switch in `Cordova 5.0.0`. Took some time, but I'm finally running `5.0.0`.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but this usually works for me. For testing purposes (not only this case, but most of errors that sometimes occur in ripple) I always give it a first try, just like:

---->line 104 on cordova.js (which you can find inside platform www)

replace

```js
if ("cordova" in window) { throw new Error("cordova already defined"); };
```

With:

```js
if ("cordova" in window) { 
    //check if emulation
    if(window.location.href.indexOf('localhost:4400') < 0){
        //if not emulating, throw error
        throw new Error("cordova already defined");
    }
};
```

If it doesn't work, then I start googling about the issue.
hope this helps somebody to save some time.